# How to set hive parameters and multiple statements in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a parquet table and the table contains a column with new line data. So when a hive query is fired on this table new line data will be considered as new records,  i can over come this in hive by setting parameter "set hive.query.result.fileformat=SequenceFile;".  Now i am migrating this parameter and MR query to be run in spark sql. Also i want to run some other queries like drop table statement before the actual query. 
My code is like below

```
spark.sql(set hive.query.result.fileformat=SequenceFile;drop table output_table; create table output_table stored as orc as select * from source_table;)
```

With this query i am getting parser error at the semicolon (;) position.  How can i properly execute above code in spark sql?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a semicolon at the end of the code. Remove your semicolon ,add parentheses, and include your set parameter variable in the spark config command. Then it should work.

ex:

```
spark = (SparkSession
           .builder
           .appName('hive_validation_test')
           .enableHiveSupport()
           .config("hive.query.result.fileformat", "SequenceFile")
spark.sql('drop table output_table').                                              
spark.sql('create table output_table stored as orc as select * from source_table').
```